# Convert all images in directory to .mp4 using ffmpeg and a timestamp order

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a directory with `.jpg` images named in **UNIX timestamp** format. How can I convert all images starting with the oldest timestamp to the newest in `.mp4` video format?

I found a solution but it uses incremental naming, like `image001`, `image002`.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Using aergistal's solution, i get an error in output:
I did as you told me, but i get an output error:

```
Input #0, concat, from 'list.txt':
Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 540x405 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[swscaler @ 0x14751c0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[libx264 @ 0x14b7120] height not divisible by 2 (540x405)
Output #0, mp4, to 'out.mp4':
Stream #0:0: Video: h264, none, q=2-31, 128 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 0:0, 30 fps
Metadata:
  encoder         : Lavc56.26.100 libx264
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Make a list of files in the order in which you want them to appear using the format:

`file '<path/to/file>'`

On Linux you can fetch the files using the timestamp order and create the list using:

```
ls /path/to/*.jpg | sort -V | xargs -I {} echo "file '{}'" > list.txt
```

From the `sort` man page:

> **-V, --version-sort**          natural sort of (version) numbers within text

Example list:

```
file '1.jpg'
file '2.jpg'
file '3.jpg'
```

Then use the FFmpeg [concat demuxer](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate) with your list:

```
ffmpeg -r 1/5 -f concat -i list.txt -c:v libx264 -r 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -t 15 out.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out! :) I get an output error, which i pasted in question description.

Comment: Actualy i solved with: ffmpeg -r 1/5 -f concat -i list.txt -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf scale=540:-2 -t 15 out.mp4

Comment: Yes, picture dimensions should be a multiple of 2

Comment: But, the image changes after 5 sec. Is it possible to have 1-2 images in 1 sec?

Comment: Of course. I gave you an example command. Change the input/output framerate and/or duration according to your needs (`-r`, `-t`)

Comment: @Jack You can also add duration for each image using the concat demuxer (although for images I'm not sure if it will ignore it or not). Might be worth a try. See the [docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat-1).