# Convert image sequence to video using ffmpeg and list of files

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I have a camera taking time-lapse shots every 2–3 seconds, and I keep a rolling record of a few days' worth. Because that's a lot of files, I keep them in subdirectories by day and hour:

```
images/
    2015-05-02/
        00/
            2015-05-02-0000-02
            2015-05-02-0000-05
            2015-05-02-0000-07
        01/
            (etc.)
    2015-05-03/
```

I'm writing a script to automatically upload a timelapse of the sunrise to YouTube each day. I can get the sunrise time from the web in advance, then go back after the sunrise and get a list of the files that were taken in that period using `find`:

```
touch -d "$SUNRISE_START" sunrise-start.txt
touch -d "$SUNRISE_END" sunrise-end.txt
find images/"$TODAY" -type f -anewer sunrise-start.txt ! -anewer sunrise-end.txt
```

Now I want to convert those files to a video with `ffmpeg`. Ideally I'd like to do this without making a copy of all the files (because we're talking ~3.5 GB per hour of images), and I'd prefer not to rename them to something like `image000n.jpg` because other users may want to access the images. Copying the images is my fallback.

But I'm getting stuck sending the results of `find` to `ffmpeg`. I understand that ffmpeg can expand wildcards internally, but I'm not sure that this is going to work where the files aren't all in one directory. I also see a few people using `find`'s `--exec` option with `ffmpeg` to do batch conversions, but I'm not sure if this is going to work with image sequence input (as opposed to, say, converting 1000 images into 1000 single-frame videos).

Any ideas on how I can connect the two—or, failing that, a better way to get files in a date range across several subdirectories into `ffmpeg` as an image sequence?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use the `concat` demuxer with a list of files. The list format is:

```
file '/path/to/file1'
file '/path/to/file2'
file '/path/to/file3'
```

Basic ffmpeg usage:

```
`ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt ... <output>`
```

[Concatenate](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate) [FFmpeg wiki]

Comment: See also [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30121222/convert-all-images-in-directory-to-mp4-using-ffmpeg-and-a-timestamp-order/30123156#30123156) here.

Comment: This sounds like exactly what I need! Might take me a couple of days to verify, though; the machine I'm running this on has `ffmpeg` 0.6.5 (`concat` was introduced in 1.1), and I'm not sure whether I have permission to update it.

Comment: You should definitely upgrade, the current version is 2.6.x.

Comment: Yeah, it's a departmental server in a uni that gets primarily used for scientific computation; I'm guessing nobody has really needed to put ffmpeg through its paces in a few years :P

Comment: For the `mylist.txt` note that `file` is not a placeholder for a filename. It should be written, literally, each time, in front of each file path.

Comment: Line 1: unknown keyword 'f'

Answer (score 4):

use `pattern_type glob` for this

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -r 25 -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg' -an -c:v libx264 -r 25 timelapse.mp4
```

Comment: Just for completion, there's another method using a format string instead of glob

https://superuser.com/a/1462082/204468

`ffmpeg -f image2 -framerate 25 -i img/%05d.jpg -vcodec libx264 -crf 22 video.mp4`

Answer (score 2):

ffmpeg probably uses the same file name globbing facility as the shell, so all valid file name globbing patterns should work.  Specifically in your case, a pattern of `images/201?-??-??/??/201?-??-??-????-??` will expand to all files in question e.g.

```
ls -l images/201?-??-??/??/201?-??-??-????-??
ffmpeg ... 'images/201?-??-??/??/201?-??-??-????-??' ...
```

Note the quotes around the pattern in the `ffmpeg` invocation: you want to pass the pattern verbatim to `ffmpeg` to expand the pattern into file names, not have the shell do the expansion.

Comment: NB; it does not use the same globbing tools and more complicated patterns like this might break things :)

Comment: @j6m8: Interesting...  Can you please point to the code or documentation that backs up your assertion?