# How to convert all PNGs in a folder to JPG in order to make a video?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am trying to have folder of images either converted to a video format I can play and edit frames of or just iterate through the folder and display them. I am using VS, C#, WPF and .NET 4.7.2.

The folder also has a .txt document named "files.txt" that has all of the files in the folder line by line.

Example (Separated by lines, not spaces)-

"
frame_000000.jpg
frame_000001.jpg
frame_000002.jpg
frame_000003.jpg
frame_000004.jpg
frame_000005.jpg
...
"

When I drop the folder into the application it begins running.

Here is what I have so far.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace WpfApp2
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public static string filename { get; set; }
        public static string imageName { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void UpdateImage()
        {
            ImportImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageName));
        }

        public void FileDropStackPanel_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
            {
                string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
                filename = Path.GetFullPath(files[0]);
                GetFileName();
            }
        }

        public void GetFileName()
        {
            listFilesInDirectory(filename);
            void listFilesInDirectory(string workingDirectory)
            {
                string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(workingDirectory);

                if (filePaths.Contains(filename + @"\files.txt"))
                {
                    string textFile = filename + @"\files.txt";
                    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(textFile);

                    for (int x = 0; x < lines.Length; x++)
                    {
                        imageName = filename + @"\" + lines[x];
                        UpdateImage();
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

First of all I had to convert all the JPG files to PNG outside of the code. Second it only shows the last image in the folder.

I can't figure out how to get the JPG into a video format or display them at 25 FPS. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You say you use an external means to convert the JPGs to PNG but that your app will work on JPG files.  Which is it?

Comment: Creating a video is a complex task.  Last I looked it was part of the DirectShow API

Comment: I need it to work with JPG but right now it only works with PNG.

Comment: Possibly useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894836/c-sharp-convert-image-formats-to-jpg or even [this](https://james-ramsden.com/c-convert-all-images-in-a-folder-from-png-to-jpg/)

Comment: Thanks for the update, I meant to ask why the _"The folder also has a **.txt document** that has **all of the files in the folder line by line**"_.  Could you not just [`Directory.EnumerateFiles()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles?view=net-5.0)?  You could make a folder called **Inbox** or something.  Good luck! :)

Comment: I don't think I'd bother inventing this wheel; I'd just ask ffmpeg to do it - https://superuser.com/questions/624567/how-to-create-a-video-from-images-using-ffmpeg - as far as I've read there isn't a way to use the file you have to specify the input files and order but you could read the file and prepare a huge command line with as many `-i` arguments as there are line of the text file. That situation may have changed; maybe ask a question on SU to see if a text file can be the driving file list for a img to movie conversion.

Comment: @CaiusJard For what it's worth, you can use a file as the list of images, though it's not a quite a simple file list:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30121222/convert-all-images-in-directory-to-mp4-using-ffmpeg-and-a-timestamp-order

Comment: At the time I wrote the comment I don't think the detail on the file naming was a part of the question - for some reason I had in mind that there were a disparate bunch of oddly named mix of PNG and JPG. Knowing that the files are regularly named with a sequential counter makes it a lot easier - ffmpeg will consume it with a couple of command line args - see https://superuser.com/questions/624567/how-to-create-a-video-from-images-using-ffmpeg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** Here is a solution to the questions that you asked that works.  I've tested it.  However, it's not ideal and I don't recommend it, because this code is dependent on how fast your system is able to perform asynchronous context switching.

1. This code works on JPG, PNG, and a few other formats. I'm not sure why you needed to convert all your JPG files to PNG.
2. The reason why your code only showed the last image in the folder is because you were running all your code synchronously on the UI thread, so it wasn't able to update the UI until your entire "for" loop was done. You need to break up the UI thread by using the async/await pattern. Look it up if you're not familiar with this way of coding.

The code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace _69201085
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void UpdateImage(string imageName)
        {
            ImportImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageName));
        }

        private async Task ShowFilesInFolder(string workingDirectory)
        {
            var textFile = Path.Combine(workingDirectory, "files.txt");
            if (File.Exists(textFile))
            {
                // Parse the file, then iterate through all of the listed images at 25 FPS
                var lines = await File.ReadAllLinesAsync(textFile);
                foreach (var line in lines)
                {
                    var imageName = Path.Combine(workingDirectory, line.Trim());
                    // Check that the file exists before you try to change the image
                    if (File.Exists(imageName))
                    {
                        // Make sure that the file is one of the approved image formats
                        if (
                            Path.GetExtension(imageName).ToLower() == ".jpg" ||
                            Path.GetExtension(imageName).ToLower() == ".png" ||
                            Path.GetExtension(imageName).ToLower() == ".jpeg" ||
                            Path.GetExtension(imageName).ToLower() == ".jfif" ||
                            Path.GetExtension(imageName).ToLower() == ".gif" ||
                            Path.GetExtension(imageName).ToLower() == ".bmp"
                            )
                        {
                            // Update the image
                            UpdateImage(imageName);

                            // If you want 25 FPS, then wait 40 ms
                            await Task.Delay(40);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private async void Window_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
            {
                string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);

                string folder = Path.GetFullPath(files[0]);
                if (!Directory.Exists(folder))
                {
                    folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(files[0]);
                }

                // Verify that the directory/folder exists
                if (Directory.Exists(folder))
                {
                    await ShowFilesInFolder(folder);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="_69201085.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" Drop="Window_Drop" AllowDrop="True">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel x:Name="FileDropStackPanel">
            <Image x:Name="ImportImage" Stretch="Fill" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Lastly, the code assumes your "files.txt" is listed without the directory name, only the file names. Like this:

```
file1.jpg
file2.PNG
file3.bmp
file4.jpg
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried running it and when I try and drop the folder of JPGs nothing happens. I see you've nested the Image into the StackPanel. What benefits does this have?

Comment: @ChaseRatliff sorry I had a logical error in my Window_Drop method. Please see the updated answer and try it again with jpg images.  I've tested it myself with files with extension ".jpg" and it works fine.  As for the StackPanel, there is no purpose for it...that was just an artifact of your original code, so you can get rid of it entirely.

Comment: Yeah I figured that part out. It was the "FullFilePath" correct? But I want to say thank you, you've given me a way better understanding of WPF and C#!

Comment: Yep, glad I could be of help.

Answer (score -1):

You may use ffmpeg and the techniques [described in this SuperUser post](https://superuser.com/questions/624567/how-to-create-a-video-from-images-using-ffmpeg) to turn your file frames into a movie

```
ffmpeg -framerate 25 -i frame_%08d.jpg out.mp4
```

If you're on Windows you might have to double up the % sign